# MySQL Where Statement While checking value

Tags: mysql

```
 $sql = "SELECT cc.name AS c_name, ev.name AS event_name, ev.eventModeId AS event_mode, ev.carClassHash, cc.carClassHash
 FROM EVENT_DATA e
INNER JOIN PERSONA p ON e.personaId = p.ID
        INNER JOIN CUSTOMCAR cc ON cc.ownedCarId = e.carId
        INNER JOIN CAR_CLASSES ccs ON ccs.store_name = cc.name
        INNER JOIN USER u ON u.ID = p.USERID
        LEFT JOIN BAN b ON b.user_id = u.ID
        INNER JOIN EVENT ev ON ev.ID = e.EVENTID
    
    WHERE (p.name = ? 
    AND ev.carClassHash = cc.carClassHash)";
```

This query works for me except I'd also like to display any `carClassHash` with the value '607077938'. Is there a way I could somehow keep the above query to check if the event hash matches the car class hash but also still display values where the carClassHash (`cc.carClassHash`) is equal to '607077938'?

Thanks! :)

Comment: There's no `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses in your query.

Comment: Show some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: It would probably be simplest to just do two queries and combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `OR` in the `WHERE` clause?

```
[...]
WHERE ((p.name = ? AND ev.carClassHash = cc.carClassHash) OR (cc.carClassHash = 607077938))
```

This should work if that value is an integer. If it's a string, use quotes around it.

Comment: @County **filter out ev.CarClassHash's that are not equal to the ev.carClassHash's** How can something not be equal to itself?

Comment: Post sample data and desired results in the question, not a comment. Make it plain text so we can paste it into tests.